# Multiple chars to end a string in jEdit syntax

Tags: regex, xml, jedit

I am writing a a syntax highlighting rule for jEdit.  I have the string rule like this.

```
<SPAN TYPE="LITERAL1" NO_LINE_BREAK="TRUE">
    <BEGIN>"</BEGIN>
    <END>"</END>
</SPAN>
```

It works fine.  The `"` char both starts and ends strings.  However, I also want the `+` char to end strings, but not start them.  However, this does not work.

```
<SPAN TYPE="LITERAL1" NO_LINE_BREAK="TRUE">
    <BEGIN>"</BEGIN>
    <END>("|+)</END>
</SPAN>
```

I also tried this, but to no avail.

```
<SPAN TYPE="LITERAL1" NO_LINE_BREAK="TRUE">
    <BEGIN>"</BEGIN>
    <END>"</END>
</SPAN>
<SPAN TYPE="LITERAL1" NO_LINE_BREAK="TRUE">
    <BEGIN>"</BEGIN>
    <END>+</END>
</SPAN>
```

I am out of ideas.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use [`SPAN_REGEXP`](http://jedit.org/users-guide/mode-rule-span-regexp.html) tag instead of `SPAN`:

```
<SPAN_REGEXP TYPE="LITERAL1" NO_LINE_BREAK="TRUE">
    <BEGIN>"</BEGIN>
    <END REGEXP="TRUE">("|\+)</END>
</SPAN_REGEXP>
```

Don't forget to escape the `+`

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but it has some issues.  The tag is SPAN_REGEXP.  Also, the <END> tag needs REGEXP="TRUE" inside it, like this: <END REGEXP="TRUE">("|\+)</END>

Comment: @Feldspar15523: You're right, fixed.